# Some users are not able to see my inserted Google Sheet in my Google Sites web pages

Tags: cookies, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sites

I have several pages of Google Sites where I have just a bit text at the top of the page and then I am simply inserting a Google sheet - nothing else.

A few users, definitely minority population going to my pages, do not see the spreadsheet, but only the text at the top.  I have been able to work with a couple of these users and found that when I cleared their cookies the webpage would load the spreadsheet properly.

Up until just recently I was unable to see this issue on any of my own computers, phone, tablets, and with any browser. I did come across this on my Mac recently using Firefox, version 23.0.1. I received the following error message -

Error: Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fspreadsheets.google.com%2Fspreadsheet%2Fpub%3Fchrome%3Dfalse%26key%3D0ArJ3-BOD3lKkdHNDQkd6LU5jSWlWaWZQWTNUcjZWTEE%26output%3Dhtml%26pubredirect%3Dtrue%26widget%3Dtrue&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fspreadsheets.google.com%2Fspreadsheet%2Fpub%3Fchrome%3Dfalse%26key%3D0ArJ3-BOD3lKkdHNDQkd6LU5jSWlWaWZQWTNUcjZWTEE%26output%3Dhtml%26pubredirect%3Dtrue%26widget%3Dtrue does not permit framing.

I cleared cookies that only had "goggle" in them, i.e. not all cookies, and the webpage loaded properly with the spreadsheet.

I have seen a number of posts with "Error: Load denied by X-Frame-Options:" but none seem to be helping me. I think this being an issue that does not always show is making it tough to de-bug.

Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.